# A homomorphism between two group cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

We have the following two facts about group cohomology: 
\begin{eqnarray}
H^2(\mathbb{Z}_n\times\mathbb{Z}_n,U(1))=\mathbb{Z}_n;\\
H^3(\mathbb{Z}_n,U(1))=\mathbb{Z}_n. 
\end{eqnarray}
My question is whether there exists the following generalization:

"There exists a monomorphism from $H^{d+1}(G,U(1))$ to $H^2([C(G)]^d,U(1))$ where $C(G)$ is the center of $G$ (or maybe we can first restrict to abelian $G$ or finite $G$)"?

Comment: What‘s $U(1)$ here?

Comment: @LukasKofler $U(1)$ is considered as a $G$-module (in the above case, it is a trivial $G$-module). It is the co-domain of co-chains.